# React throw error while using ReactRouter useLocation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

[image]

Have an error about `useContext` while use React Router `useLocation` hook.

I'm trying to get info about page current location, with `useLocation`, and getting this error:

`useContext is undefined.`

```
import React from 'react';
import Welcome from './Components/Welcome/Welcome';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Link,
    Route,
    Switch,
    Redirect,
    useLocation,
} from 'react-router-dom'
import app from "./firebase"

const  App = () => {
let location = useLocation()

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        
          
          <Route path = "/welcome">
          <Welcome  />
          </Route>
          
          <Route path="/ui">
        
          <UI/>
        </Route>
      
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

const UI = () => {
  return(
    <h1>UI i am</h1>
  )
}

export default App;
```

package-json:
[image]

Comment: you cant use useLocation or other hooks out of BrowserRouter, please read doc [Reack Router Dom useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useLocation` hooks must be used inside of `BrowserRouter` but you are defining it before defining your `BrowserRouter` (which is defined as `Router`)

First, define your `Router`, assume we have one page/view in our example:

```
const  App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path = "/welcome">
           <Welcome  />
        </Route>
   </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Now, in the `Welcome`:

```
const Welcome = () => {
   let location = useLocation()
   
   return (
       // rest of your codes
   )
}
```